# Unable to add IP address as authoritative DNS on GoDaddy

Tags: dns, godaddy

So I got this email recently:

> Hello,
>
> This is the 1st follow-up notice in regards to your recent reseller
>   server migration.
>
> Our administrators have discovered that your domains on your server
>   still need to be updated at your domain registrar due to the migration
>   of your account to a new server. Without this change, your sites will
>   no longer operate correctly once the previous server is disconnected.
>   We ask that you make the following changes to your domains' DNS in
>   order to ensure continued operation of your websites:
>
> -- The following domain(s) use GoDaddy for DNS.
>
> user domain.tld => 192.185.144.90
>
> If you do not take action before  you WILL experience a service
>   interruption. We recommend making these changes at your earliest
>   possible convenience.
>
> If you require any assistance updating your DNS records at your domain
>   registrar, our support staff is standing by to guide you through the
>   process and answer any questions that you may have. We also have a
>   wide variety of tutorials covering most of the popular domain
>   registrars to assist you:

When I log into `godaddy.com` it says my authoritative name servers are `ns51.domaincontrol.com` and `ns52.domaincontrol.com`.

I can confirm that my domain (`domain.tld`) is active on that DNS by doing `nslookup -vc -query=all domain.tld ns51.domaincontrol.com`. I can also confirm that it's active on `192.185.144.90` by doing an `nslookup` with `192.185.144.90` instead of `ns51.domaincontrol.com`. But when I try to change the nameserver on `godaddy.com`, I get a "Invalid TLD error" error, as though GoDaddy only accepts domain names instead of IP addresses for authoritative DNS.

Any ideas?

A screenshot is attached:
[image: godaddy screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Occasionally GoDaddy's hosting department will relocate their shared hosting accounts to a new shared server, generally with updated hardware. The new server will have a different IP address, and if you were allocated a dedicated IP address for an SSL certificate (or purchased a dedicated IP address separately), that IP address would also change.

If you're using their "Standard" nameservers (as selected in the screenshot), you don't need to change its IP address since they manage those. You would have to change any `A` records in your DNS settings that point to the old IP address to the new IP address.

Log into your GoDaddy account and click on the `Launch` button in the `Domains` section under the `Products` tab. This will bring up the `Domains Control Panel` - select your domain from the list there by clicking on it. That will then display your `Domain Details` - click on the `DNS Zone File` tab.

Under the `A (Host)` record, you should see an `@` followed by an IP address. Confirm that the new IP address listed in the email you received is the same that's there. If not, then click the `Edit` button, followed by clicking on the IP address to edit it (if you see the old IP address in other records, then change it to the new IP address also); then click the `Save Zone File` button.

What this accomplishes is letting other DNS servers and clients know the IP address of the new server or dedicated IP. It could take up to 72 hours to resolve everywhere.

If you have any other questions or problems, contact their support team by phone if possible and select the options to speak with their hosting or domain support departments.